# change Related Products in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

As you know, woocommerce filters related products according to their tags and categories. Because of that, in a big shopping website with so many products, most of the time, it shows irrelevant related products compared to main product.

I want to change how it works. I mean I want to show related products according to the name of the main product. All my similar products have the same name, except the color. So, if I can add a hack code to filter related products according names, it would be much more useful.

Example : assume I have a products that its name is "Ascis Gel Cumulus 15 Men Black", if I have a code to filter products based on exact similar words, that would be great.

---> show as related products if they have exactly 6 similar exact words. if not, show products having exactly 5 similar words, if not show products having exactly 4 similar words and so on...

I'd really appreciate if you guys could help me with that.

P.s : I guess this webiste sort them according names.

http://www.barcin.com/nike-air-max-2014-spor-ayakkabi-621077-009

Answer (score 0):

> Because of that, in a big shopping website with so many products, most of the time, it shows irrelevant related products compared to main product.

I don't fully agree with this statement. If  "Ascis Gel Cumulus 15 Men Black" and "Ascis Gel Domain 15 Men Black" are both in the Asics category they will be related. They could have Gel Cumulus and Gel Domain as sub categories, or tags. I don't know, but it strikes me that if you categorize and tag things efficiently you will get better related products. I think you could also maybe add custom attributes with the following suggestion.

That said, I believe it is possible to adjust how the related products are queried. However, this is not an easy feat since I am not so good in SQL so I will only be able to provide a partial answer. If you look at the `single-product/related.php` template you will see

`$related = $product->get_related( $posts_per_page );`

and you can trace the `get_related()` function back to the product class in 
`abstract-wc-product.php`.

Looking at `get_related()` it sets up an advanced SQL query, but you can filter the query clauses via the `woocommerce_product_related_posts_query` filter.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_related_posts_query'. so_26246618_product_related_posts_query', 10, 2 );

function so_26246618_product_related_posts_query( $query, $product ){

    global $wpdb;

    $query['join']   = // write a new join clause;
    $query['where'] = // write a new where clause

    return $query;

}
```

Or optionally, if the `woocommerce_product_related_posts_relate_by_category` filter is true, the query will relate the products by product category. Likewise, if the `woocommerce_product_related_posts_relate_by_tag` filter is set to true then the query will relate the products by tags. Both of these are set to true by default. You could disable them both, but then I don't know that you'd be doing anything more than querying the most recent products without writing your own custom SQL.